# Anaconda 1.9.1 installation related help required

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda 1.9.1 and Minicoda3 twice on my Windows 7 machine. Every time, after installation, I tried to use command `conda info` or try to create environment using conda, I get this message:

```
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to install Anaconda 1.9.1 on windows 8 machine and everything works there but not on windows 7 machine. Do I need to configure few extra things for Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I think you are asking this on a wrong forum. Anaconda has a official user forum supported by their staff who can help you better [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda)

Comment: Ashish it's fine to ask questions here. StackOverflow is a forum for all programming related questions. And several employees of Continuum (myself included) follow questions here with the Anaconda tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add `;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts` to your path.

See http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx for step-by-step directions.

This tells the system where to look for conda when you try to run it.

Comment: I added these paths but still getting same issue

Comment: I could not find why conda command is not working even though both paths are added in environment variable path. However your answer provided me hint to access conda command. Thanks

Comment: There is an option to do this automatically in the installer, and I believe it is checked by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue mentioned in the question, the solution who solved my problem is described [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/41). In the end, I modified anaconda.bat to match:

```
@echo off

rem +===========================================================================
rem | Initialisation
rem +===========================================================================

for %%i in ("%~dp0..\envs") do (
    set ANACONDA_ENVS=%%~fi
)

if not "%1" == "" (
    if not exist "%ANACONDA_ENVS%\%1\python.exe" (
        echo No environment named "%1" exists in %ANACONDA_ENVS%
        goto :eof
    )
    set ANACONDA_ENV_NAME=%1
    set ANACONDA="%ANACONDA_ENVS%\%1"
    title Anaconda (%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%^)
) else (
    set ANACONDA_ENV_NAME=
    for %%i in ("%~dp0..") do (
        set ANACONDA=%%~fi
    )
    title Anaconda
)

set ANACONDA_SCRIPTS=%ANACONDA%\Scripts
set PATH=%ANACONDA%;%ANACONDA_SCRIPTS%;%PATH%
echo Added %ANACONDA% and %ANACONDA_SCRIPTS% to PATH.

if not "%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%" == "" (
    echo Activating environment %ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%...
    set PROMPT=[%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%] $P$G
)
```

Then, everything became alright!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well on Win7. For me, Anaconda was installed in 
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Contunuum\Anaconda`, instead of `C:\Anaconda`. Adding that, along `with C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Contunuum\Anaconda\Scripts` to my Path solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the given answers work, like in my case, open a console, navigate to the `Scripts` folder in the `Anaconda` folder `C:\Anaconda\Scripts`, and there should be `conda.exe`.

From it you can execute the command.